# Function main is missing while compiling with Makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile

I am trying to compile source codes into binary.

Of the two source files, the main function is defined in one(main.c). However I still get the following error while compiling my sources into a binary.

Here is my Makefile:

```
CC      = gcc
LD      = ld
AR      = ar
NM      = nm
OBJCOPY = objcopy
OBJDUMP = objdump
READELF = readelf


CFLAGS += -Wall   -I.
LDADD +=  -lpthread -ldl -L. -llob

BINARY=test

.PHONY: all
all: $(BINARY)

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

sub.o:  sub.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(BINARY): sub.o main.o 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDADD) -o $@ $<  

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(BINARY)
```

this returns error:

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Please advise!

Answer (score 1):

The error stems from this part

```
$(BINARY): sub.o main.o 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDADD) -o $@ $<
```

The variable `$<` refers only to the first dependency, which is `sub.o` here. `main.o` is hence not linked. The fix is to modify the compile command to

```
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDADD) -o $@ $^
```

where `$^`refers to all prerequesites (thanks to @MadScientist for pointing that out). You might also consider storing source and object files in a variable. I'd suggest replacing your rules for compiling sources and linking by the following

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=%.o)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(BINARY): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDADD) -o $@ $(OBJ)
```

Here, all .c files in the current directories are compiled into object files and then linked into the executable (adjust the `wildcard` line if you don't want every .c file but rather a certain selection).

Comment: You can use `$^` to mean all the prerequisites.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html